# Create generic class just by type argument?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generics

How can I create a generic class, which takes the class type from the generic type argument that is placed when creating/injecting this generic class?
My goal is to specify eg `MyGeneric<User>`, and the generic class should then be capable to use the `User` class in all method calls. Without having to explicitly supplying `User.class` in the constructor of the generic additionally.

Something like:

```
class MyGeneric<T> {
    public MyGeneric() {
        someService.create(Class<T>, someString);
    }
}

class Usage {
    @Inject
    MyGeneric<User> myuser;
}
```

How is this done propertly?

Comment: Why? This would not allow MyGeneric to use the methods of T. MyGeneric could only use the methods of the upper bound of T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is write the instantiation code in a superclass and then extend it for each particular generic type (little or no code is required in subclasses, but the subclasses are mandatory as they're the only way to avoid type erasure):

```
abstract class MyGeneric<T> {

    private T instance;

    public MyGeneric(String str) {
        // grab the actual class represented by 'T'
        // this only works for subclasses of MyGeneric<T>, not for MyGeneric itself !
        Class<T> genericType = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        try {
            // instantiate that class with the provided parameter
            instance = genericType.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(str);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
}

class MyUser extends MyGeneric<User> {
    public MyUser() {
        // provide the string to use for instantiating users...
        super("userStr");
    }
}

class User { /*...*/ }
```

Edit: made the generic class `abstract` to enforce the usage of subclasses.

It can also be used with anonymous classes like:

`new MyGeneric<User>("..string...") {}`

I think this is the closest to your initial goal you can get...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it, due to runtime [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

The usual way is (as you alluded) to pass an instance of `Class<T>` - called a [type token](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) - to the constructor. Given your code pattern, you're stuck with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky but with e.g. TypeLiteral from Guice you can do things like:

```
public class ReiHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {

   private final TypeLiteral<K> keyTL;

   public ReiHashMap(TypeLit<K> keyTL ) {
       this.keyTL = keyTL;
   }

   @Override
   public V get(Object o) {
       if ( !keyTL.getRawType().isAssignableFrom( o.getClass() )) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException( "object " + o + " (class "+ o.getClass() +")ist not of type " + keyTL);
       }
       return super.get(o);
   }
   ...
```

this is an extension to HashMaps that can check the type of the argument of get at runtime.